# Compatibility issues with jquery libs

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am working on a crm adding some features. One of them was to use ajax to post to another page a use the returned information to fill out some forms. It worked great. I am using $.post and all that good stuff. I then noticed that one of the other prewritten features of the site stopped working. So I started poking around and the feature that stopped working was giving this error in the console log.

> [19:15:21.013] TypeError: $("view_Option").selectedIndex is undefined @ http://test.com/crm/modules/Calendar/script.js:598

So ok I figured I was linking to jquery twice or something along those lines so I commented out that line and it works. So I check my code to make sure that works too and now I get

> [19:13:40.312] TypeError: $.post is not a function @ http://test.com/crm/modules/Calendar/renterAutoUpdate.js:16

Can someone explain to me the reason this is happening and how I would go about fixing something like this?

[Edit] The line that determines whether my code or the prewritten code is going to work is

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably you've commented out the line, that was used elsewhere in your project. Try uncommenting it again and see what happens. The $.post is not a function should gone, and you should get back your first error.

If it happens, you have to fight back the first error, which is probably that jQuery doesnt have the .selectedIndex. Instead, you should write:

```
$("view_Option")[0].selectedIndex
```

Try this, and write, what happens.

Comment: var OptionData = $('view_Option').options[$('view_Option').selectedIndex].value;

This is the line it is refering to. I tried to add [0] after the second view option but no go. Its referencing to a drop down list.

Comment: It doesnt work. I forgot to add that part to my last comment.

Comment: You can access the value of the dropdown list just by typing `$("#selectId").val()`. Can you access the required dropdown by its #id?

Answer (score 1):

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
var $jq = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
```

And then I did

```
$jq.post(
```

instead of

```
$.post(
```

Fixed all my issues for anyone else having this same problem